# VBA macro to remove everything before and after <div> tag

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm creating a report that has a column with lots of cells that have HTML tags in almost every box. I'm trying to create a VBA macro that will remove some HTML tags from this column.

So in one situation, I have:

```
<h1>text text.........text</h1>
<p>text text.........text</p>
<div class="Take"> text text.........text </div>
<p>text text.........text</p>
<div class="Found">
 <div class="Deficient">
 <p>text text.........text</p>
 <p>text text.........text</p>
<img>....</img>
```

I just listed only some HTML tags, but there are more.

What I want is to extract only the content between the `<div class=...>` tags and keep the div tag itself. The rest should be removed

```
<h1>text text.........text</h1>
<div class="Take"> text text.........text </div>
<div class="Found"> text text.........text </div>
<div class="Deficient"> text text.........text </div>
```

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Please take the time to format your question correctly. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Each each line a field? For example is `<h1>text text.........text</h1>` in A1 and 
`<p>text text.........text</p>` in B1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824872/writing-macro-in-excel-to-remove-html-tag

Comment: Does this have to be a macro?

Comment: Dave, I have an excel file, but if you know another way, that's not complicated, please tel me

Comment: well that stips the html tags, but I don't want that. I need to delete everything exept the above tags and content inside the specified tags. For the div tag I have only 3 class ID's

Comment: The `img` tag is not well formed, it should be self closing

Comment: it was just an quick example

Comment: please correct your quick example. As it currently stands, I don't understand how `<div class="Found">` results in `<div class="Found"> text text.........text </div>`. That *text* is part of the inner `<div class="Deficient"`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Excel find and replace.

Search for the tag such as `<h1>` and replace it with nothing (empty/white space). Then do the same with the closing tag '' which will leave content.

EG

```
<h1>My content</h1>
```

will become

```
My content
```

For other tags were you need to remove tag and content, use the wildcard `*`.

Search for `<p>*</p>` and replace with white space! This will remove the entire entry.

And for self closing tabs, like IMG, you can do `<img*/>`

Comment: Inside the div tags that I want to keep, there are some paragraph tags that I want to keep

Comment: Your question is poor then, it doesn't make this clear. However, it also sounds like there is no consistent logic (how does any one know that you want to keep some nested P tags and not others)? If there is no logic, then you can't program it.

Answer (score 0):

This should pull it out, replace the msgbox with where you want the value to print and adjust the range accordingly. If these aren't specific `cells` then you could try searching by `row`.

```
Sub test()

Dim c As Range
Dim sFound As String
Dim sValue As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
For Each c In Range("A:A")
    If Not c.Find("<div class") Is Nothing Then
       sFound = c.Value
       i = InStr(sFound, ">")
       j = InStr(sFound, "</div")
       sValue = Mid(sFound, i + 1, j - i - 1)

       MsgBox (sValue)

    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

for instance, instead of `msgbox(svalue)` you could go with

```
dim k as integer
k=1

worksheets("sheet2").cells(k,1) = svalue
k=k+1
```

to move it to another sheet.

If you have some `<div class` that have no `</div>` or anything inside, throw in a `on error resume next`

Comment: woow, thanks. I need to make it work for all cells in column B in sheet1. Can you tell me how to replace msgbox(svalue) in this situation?

Comment: you change `for each c in range` to `B:B`

Comment: I'm curious, does this work for `<div>` `</div>` tags spanned over multiple lines like his example shows?

Comment: @nixda no, it's only looking in one cell at a time

Comment: Of course, if someone needs to alter it, one could change the `for each c` to `for each row from y to z` of some sort, looking in x rows each pass. It shouldn't pick up duplicates if it's incrementing properly. You'd have to join the multiple rows to a string variable though, to use `instr`.